# Cabal output is redirected but not generated

Tags: testing, haskell, build, cabal

I have a fairly simple haskell project set up, where I just want to have the framework working with testing and so on before I actually start coding. I have my source files for an executable in a `/src` directory (where `/` is the project's root) and my tests in a `/testsuite` directory. `/testsuite` contains a simple test file called `TestSuite.hs` with `main = Test.Framework.defautMain tests` as the implementation of main. The problem is, when I run

```
cabal clean && cabal configure --enable-tests && cabal build
```

I get the warning

```
output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated because there is no main module.
```

The build works fine when I don't specify `--enable-tests`. My cabal file is:

```
Name:                Example
Version:             0.1
Synopsis:            Synopsis
Description:
    Long description.
License:             GPL
License-File:        LICENSE
Author:              SeanK
Maintainer:          email@example.com
Category:            Development
Build-Type:          Simple
Cabal-Version:       >= 1.8

Test-Suite test
    Type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
    Main-Is:            TestSuite.hs
    Build-Depends:      base >= 3 && < 5,
                        test-framework,
                        test-framework-quickcheck
                        -- QuickCheck
    Hs-Source-Dirs:     src,
                        testsuite

Executable example
    Main-Is:            Main.hs
    -- Other-Modules:       
    Build-Depends:      base >= 3 && < 5,
                        haskell98
    Hs-Source-Dirs:     src
    Ghc-Options:        -Wall
```

I have QuickCheck disabled because I'm not using (==>) at the moment, which is the only function I currently need from it. The rest should be straight-forward. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should define module name in your `TestSuite.hs` file as `Main`, like [there](https://github.com/selectel/bson-haskell/blob/master/tests/Tests.hs) for example.

A quote from [The Haskell 98 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/modules.html):

> A Haskell program is a collection of modules, one of which, by convention, must be called Main and must export the value main.

Comment: Wow, this requirement really needs to be highlighted more in the error output. Compilation gives almost no hints at what is the problem. I assumed pointing out the module with main-is would suffice.

Comment: @worldsayshi I had [a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28502176/94687) after I gave explicitly a name (`MyProgram`) to my module in the source code (`myProgram.lhs`), but if I add `-main-is MyProgram.main` to the ghc command (`ghc -Wall myProgram -main-is MyProgram.main`), it does generate the executable (`./myProgram`). Contrary to your observation that `-main-is` doesn't suffice. For bare `ghc` it's sufficient in my case, perhaps, it's not going well if the compilation is done by `cabal` as in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of renaming the `TestSuite` module as Fedor suggests you could add a GHC option to set the name of the main module to your Cabal file:

```
Test-Suite testFedor
    ghc-options:    -main-is TestSuite
```

Apparently Cabal `main-is` and GHC `main-is` are different. I don't know in what way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an [hpack](https://github.com/sol/hpack)-compliant system such as Stack, cabal2nix or just the `hpack` tool, you can generate the `.cabal` file from a `package.yaml` file. For entries under `executables:` in `package.yaml` you may specify a `main:` key that works in one of two ways:

1. Given an `.hs` filename that filename will be copied directly into the `main-is:` line in the generated Cabal file, providing the Cabal semantics.
2. Given a module name or module and exported definition name (e.g., `Foo` or `Foo.startup`) the appropriate `ghc-options: -main-is ...` will be added to the generated Cabal file and `main-is:` will be a filename generated from the module name (e.g. `main-is: Foo.hs`).

If you're not wanting to use a `package.yaml` but are having difficulty with getting your Cabal file to work correctly, it may still be worth setting up a temporary, minimal `package.yaml` and running `hpack` on it just to see the output it produces and confirm that you're writing your Cabal file the same way.

For what it's worth, here's an example of an `exectuables:` section from `package.yaml` in one of my recent projects:

```
executables:
  hello:
    source-dirs: src/
    main: Hello.main
```

and the relevant fragments of the code in my generated `.cabal` file:

```
executable hello
  main-is: Hello.hs
  hs-source-dirs:
    src/
  ghc-options: -main-is Hello
```