# Where do I find (and run) an executable compiled with a cabal sandbox?

Tags: haskell, testing, compilation, executable, cabal

I'm compiling my `myProgram.lhs` with the use of a cabal sandbox (set up with `cabal sandbox init`). I'm using a simplest approach I've come up with:

```
cabal exec -- ghc myProgram
```

or (having a rule in `Makefile`)

```
cabal exec -- make myProgram
```

After that, in my source directory, appears `myProgram.o`, but not the executable `myProgram`.

How do I run the resulting program?

```
cabal exec -- ./myProgram
```

doesn't work.

Now, I've come up with a simplest approach to test it:

```
cabal exec -- runghc myProgram.lhs
```

but I don't like this.

Do you know where the resulting executable is?

(I haven't created any cabal file for my project yet. I simply used to compile the program with bare `ghc` and test it, then--when I needed custom dependencies--I set up the cabal sanbox and installed the dependencies manually there.)

Comment: Did you check in `dist/`. I'm just guessing since I don't know what is in your cabal file. IF you did `cabal install` then your executable should be somewhere in `.cabal-sandbox/bin`.

Comment: @JuanPablo No, my situation is "simpler": in that I simply use the sandbox as an environment to compile it (to run `ghc` with all the needed versions of packages, manually installed), but I haven't written a cabal specification for my program. So, basically, if I didn't need specific versions of used packages, I would simply run `ghc` to get the executable. But since I needed specific package versions (incompatible with my main system), I set up a cabal sandbox (simply to run ghc inside). So, cabal knows nothing about my executable.

Comment: What is the output of those commands?

Comment: @JustinWood Thanks for trying to help. Actually, the problem was not related to the cabal sandbox at all, it's the same for bare `ghc` and stems from my inattentiveness: I simply gave a name explicitly to my module in the source (at the same time when I started to use the cabal sandbox), and if the name is not `Main`, ghc doesn't generate an executable. Very simple! Like answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12133749/94687

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This didn't actually look like a problem of `cabal exec`, and it wasn't!

#### My history

Simultaneously with starting to use the cabal sandbox, I explicitly gave a custom name to my module in the source file (`myProgram.lhs`). And in such case just a bare `ghc` (without `cabal exec`) wouldn't generate the executable, too, as answered in [Cabal output is redirected but not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12133749/94687). (I simply couldn't test the bare `ghc` command, because I had the dependencies in the sandbox, so my module wouldn't compile.)

#### Explanation

Explanation quoted from [that Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12133749/94687):

> I get the warning
>
> ```
> output was redirected with -o, but no output will be generated because there is no main module.
> ```
>
> A quote from The Haskell 98 Report:
>
> ```
> A Haskell program is a collection of modules, one of which, by convention, must be called Main and must export the value main.
> ```

#### The solution

A solution is to add `-main-is MyProgram.main` to ghc opts. Then it generates the executable.

`./myProgram` simply appears in my source directory now, no matter whether I call

```
ghc -main-is MyProgram.main myProgram
```

or

```
cabal exec -- ghc -main-is MyProgram.main myProgram
```